# Accessing a BST in a singly linked list

Tags: c++

Having a singly linked list with its nodes being BST's, what is the code in c++ which needs to be used in order for me to be able to access the elements of the BST?

```
ifstream isd;

isd.open ( "book1.txt" );
while( !isd.eof (  ) ) {
    book b1;

    isd >> b1;
    b[i] = b1;
    i++;
}

isd.close (  );
int j = 0;

for( int k = 0; k < 104; k++ ) {
    if( b[k].category == "adventure" )
        bcat[j].insert ( b[k] );
    if( b[k].category == "family" )
        bcat[j + 1].insert ( b[k] );
    if( b[k].category == "fiction" )
        bcat[j + 2].insert ( b[k] );
    if( b[k].category == "fun" )
        bcat[j + 3].insert ( b[k] );
    if( b[k].category == "history" )
        bcat[j + 4].insert ( b[k] );
    if( b[k].category == "horror" )
        bcat[j + 5].insert ( b[k] );
}

if( b[k].category == "mystery" )
    bcat[j + 6].insert ( b[k] );
if( b[k].category == "school" )
    bcat[j + 7].insert ( b[k] );
if( b[k].category == "science" )
    bcat[j + 8].insert ( b[k] );
if( b[k].category == "story" )
    bcat[j + 9].insert ( b[k] );
if( b[k].category == "suspence" )
    bcat[j + 10].insert ( b[k] );


for( int k = 0; k < 11; k++ )
    sdb.insert ( bcat[k] );

BinNode < Elem > preorder ( BinNode < Elem > *subroot )
{
    if( subroot == NULL )
        break;
    book ele;

    return ele = subroot->val (  );
}

for( b1.setStart (  ); b1.getValue ( ro ); b1.next (  ) ) {
    b2 = ro.getroot (  );
    b3 = b2->val (  );
    if( r.Category == b3.category ) {   //compare titles in order to find the correct title 
    }
}
```

After reading from the file the `book`s..i inserted them into an array of bst depending on their category then i inserted them into the linked list. I just need to be able to access the nodes of the bst.

```
BST<string,book,titlebookcomp,bookcomp> ro;
BinNode<book> b2;
book b3;
```

Comment: What code do you have already and what is the problem you are having using it? SO is a question and answer site, not a "write my code, please" site. :) http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: if (b[k].category=="mystery")
  bcat[j+6].insert(b[k]);
 if (b[k].category=="school")
  bcat[j+7].insert(b[k]);
 if (b[k].category=="science")
  bcat[j+8].insert(b[k]);
 if (b[k].category=="story")
  bcat[j+9].insert(b[k]);
 if (b[k].category=="suspence")
  bcat[j+10].insert(b[k]);
 }
 for(int k=0;k<11;k++)
  sdb.insert(bcat[k]);

Comment: BinNode<Elem> preorder(BinNode<Elem>* subroot) 
  {
   if (subroot == NULL) break;
   book ele;
   return ele=subroot->val();
  }

for(b1.setStart();b1.getValue(ro);b1.next())
 {
  b2=ro.getroot();
  b3=b2->val();
  if(r.Category==b3.category)
  {
   //compare titles in order to find the correct title
  }
 }

Comment: after reading from the file the books..i inserted them into an array of bst depending on their category then i inserted them into the linked list. I just need to be able to access the nodes of the bst.BST<string,book,titlebookcomp,bookcomp> ro;
 BinNode<book> b2;
 book b3;

Comment: @John, you should remove the comments and edit the question instead. comments lost all the formatting.

Comment: Something wrong with `std::list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not roll your own algorithm? How are the BSTs ordered in the list? It should be a fairly simple exercise to do this. I'm not sure there is built-in (e.g. STL) support for lists of BSTs. If you clarify your problem, lots of people here would help you write an algorithm to do anything you want.

EDIT:

Here's some pseudocode. Tell me what is wrong about this or where you are having trouble implementing it:

```
  FindBook(mylist, cat, tit)
   1. while mylist != null do
   2.    if mylist.root.category = cat then
   3.       BSTnode = mylist.root
   4.       while BSTnode != null do
   5.          if BSTnode.title = tit then
   6.             print "Found title %s, category %s in BST %s", tit, cat, mylist
   7.             return true
   8.          elsif BSTnode.title < tit then
   9.             BSTnode = BSTnode.right
  10.          else
  11.             BSTnode = BSTnode.left
  12.    mylist = mylist.next
  13. print "Did not find title %s, category %s", tit, cat
  14. return false
```

Comment: The Bsts are "books" where they are ordered by their category and each book contains a title. Im not being able to create an algorithm which will let me access a specific node in the bst corresponding to the title i have. I need to be able to search the list for the category i want and after finding it i will need to search the bst for the node containing the title of the book im looking for.

Comment: thank you very much the pesudocode answered my question. :)